# Get noNameSpaceSchemaLocation from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, schema, xmlreader

I'm trying to read a xml-file with it's schema.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PersonList 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\MySchema.xsd">
```

Now I'm reading the xml file like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("MyXmlFile.xml", settings))
{
    while(reader.Read())
    //.....
}

private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
    else
    Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);

}
```

The problem is that when the schema 'D:\MySchema.xsd' is not found, it's still reading the xml so `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is useless... 
So I've set the Schema path in my code like this:

```
settings.Schemas.Add(null, "D:\\MySchema.xsd");
```

And now it's reading the xml file by using the schema, but I'm setting here the schema path hardcoded...
I want to get the schema path (noNamespaceSchemaLocation) from the xml file and add the schema to the settings depending on the schema from the xml file. By doing it like this, I can also check if the Schema exists or not.

To make it clear: How can I get the noNamespaceSchemaLocation from a xml file?

Answer (score 0):

`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="anyURI"`

You probably need to specify the location as a uri, so something like `file://d:/myschema.xsd`

Comment: I found out that using `settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;` will make the `XMLReader` use the schema file, but the `XMLReader` will still read the xml file even though the schema was not found. That's why I want to get the schema path from the xml file and check if the file exists.

Comment: It's just an attribute with a namespace. Read the attribute & then use File.Exists on the location you get.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the framework load the value of `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute as it is the standard attribute defined for the class? Could be an enhancement to XML library to load the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute value to some property under Schemas so that it will be easier for developer to extract the value and check if the file exists or not and proceed to validate the Xml.